# visual studio code - syntax highlighting for html strings?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, template-literals

[image]

I've been trying to solve this problem for 3 days already but I can't seem to find any extension to have syntax highlighting for strings that used backticks(I don't know what is the general term for this kind of strings). But if there are no extensions to enable syntax highlight for this kind of strings, is there any settings for vscode that enables me to syntax higlight?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To follow-up on Matt Bierner's previous answer.

You should use this Visual Studio Code extension:
**angular2-inline**

> This extension replaces the language-vscode-javascript-angular2 extension.

here is the extension page with the how to install
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline

Answer (score 5):

I'm on the VSCode team, and this is not something that we currently support. [Here's the feature request tracking this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2000).

In the meantime, [try out the language-vscode-javascript-angular2  extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nwallace.language-vscode-javascript-angular2). It adds syntax highlighting for html elements inside of template strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**`es6-string-html`**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobermory.es6-string-html) extension and then add a language comment before any multiline strings like this:

```js
var html = /*html*/`<div>Hello</div>`
var css = /*css*/`body { color: green }`
```

[image: Demo of Syntax Highlighting]