# Can I get code highlight / intellisense inside these backticks in Visual code

Tags: html, typescript, visual-studio-code

I want some sort of code highlight and IntelliSense if possible inside backticks (``` `` ```) in a `.ts` file for Visual Code. i.e:

```
let html =`<div><span>Hello</span></div>`;
```

If you've used or try it out in Atom or can try it out in Atom, you'll know what I meant or see the following screenshot

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [visual studio code - syntax highlighting for html strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985912/visual-studio-code-syntax-highlighting-for-html-strings)

Comment: improved question by formatting and better title

Answer (score 0):

I knew about angular2-inline but I want it for just in .ts files. However, I've found a trick. If you create something like this it'll work (not for emmet, though)

let html = 
{
   template: `<h1>Hello</h1>`
} ;
this will trick the extension to think it's a template in angular.